# How do I get a previous value of a random generated numbers 1 to 10?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a random generator from 1 to 10 that produces non repeating values
I am trying to get the previous value.
So if current is 5 and then 8
Previous 8 and next is 9, etc

This is my code:

```
var randomNumbers = [];
var numRandoms = 11;
var myVar = setInterval(randomUnique1to10, 5000);

function randomUnique1to10() {
// refill the array if needed
if (!randomNumbers.length) {
    for (var i = 1; i < numRandoms; i++) {
        randomNumbers.push(i);
    }
}
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNumbers.length);
var val = randomNumbers[index];

 if (i === 1) { // i would become 0
    i = randomNumbers.length; // so put it at the other end of the array
}
i = i - 1; // decrease by one
previous = randomNumbers[i]; // give us back the item of where we are now


randomNumbers.splice(index, 1);
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example of input and expected output? I'm not understanding what you're looking to get.

Comment: if array =[4]
    curr = 4 and prev n/a
if array=[3,4]
    curr =4 and prev =3
if array =[3,4,9]
    curr =9 and prev =4, etc..

Comment: Array is filled with values 1 to 10 in random
I need to know current - array(index-1)

Comment: you would need to store the previous before creating a new one

Comment: u need make one additional var. so when u use previous = randomNumbers[i]. var **i** not become NaN on second result.

Comment: Denny, not following you..

Comment: @user5451365 Did you see the solution I posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally what you're looking for. Hope it helps!.

```js
var randomNumbers = []; 
var numRandoms = 11; 
var myVar = setInterval(randomUnique1to10, 1000); 

shuffle = function(o){ 
 for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
  return o;
};
var finalArray = shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);
function randomUnique1to10() { 
// refill the array if needed 
if (!randomNumbers.length) { 
 for (var i = 1, l = 11; i < l; i++) { } 
} 

// var finalArray = shuffle(randomNumbers);
document.write(finalArray + "<br/>");
randomNumbers = finalArray;
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNumbers.length); 
var val = randomNumbers[index]; 
if (i === 1) { // i would become 0 
i = randomNumbers.length; // so put it at the other end of the array 
} 
x = index-1; // decrease by one 
current = randomNumbers[randomNumbers.length - 1]; // give us back the item of where we are now 
previous = randomNumbers[randomNumbers.length - 2]; 
if(previous === undefined) 
{ 
 previous = "n/a"; 
}

randomNumbers.pop(); 
if(randomNumbers.length <= 0){
 finalArray = shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);
}

document.write("Current >> " + current + " and previous = " +previous + "<br/>") 
}
```

Comment: Hi Henry
Thank you sooo much
I had to make a small change and switch current for previus and previus for current
Now my numbers are repeating them selves and are not non repeating..
Any ideas?

Comment: Here is logging:

Current >> 5 and previous = 4
Current >> 9 and previous = 5
Current >> 8 and previous = 9
Current >> 8 and previous = 8
Current >> 5 and previous = 8
Current >> 6 and previous = 5
Current >> 8 and previous = 6

Comment: @user5451365 Well I'm not really sure what changes you made (I dont think you need to make changes since I have done everything for you already) I did what you asked which was show current and prev numbers. At least I deserve you mark my answer as the correct one and vote it up. Thank you :)

Comment: Do you want to see my output?

Comment: @user5451365 I want to see your code after the changes you made and your output too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128670/discussion-between-henrydev-and-user5451365).

Comment: Let's go to the chat room

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var randomNumbers = [];
var numRandoms = 11;
var myVar = setInterval(randomUnique1to10, 5000);
var x;
function randomUnique1to10() {
// refill the array if needed
if (!randomNumbers.length) {
    for (var i = 1; i < numRandoms; i++) {
        randomNumbers.push(i);
    }
}
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNumbers.length);
var val = randomNumbers[index];

 if (i === 1) { // i would become 0
    i = randomNumbers.length; // so put it at the other end of the array
}
x = index-1; // decrease by one
previous = randomNumbers[x]; // give us back the item of where we are now


var res = randomNumbers.splice(index, 1);

console.log("result: "+res);
console.log("prev  : "+previous);
console.log("Rand  : "+randomNumbers);
}
```

NOTE:
**this code have, one problem, if res = min(array) then prev will become unidentify**

Comment: Denny, It is not doing what I expect:
    result: 9
    prev  : 8
    Rand  : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10

 result: 3
 prev  : 2
 Rand  : 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,10

result: 1
prev  : undefined
Rand  : 2,4,5,6,7,8,10

It is not getting the previous, but if it is 5, prev is 4  ... if it is 8, prev is 7 ->> Incorrect  - It is not following the random order

Comment: so, if array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10] you want to having curent = 10 and prev = 9??

Comment: In your array above, current is 10 and previous is 8
The numbers are generated randomly so first number could be [6] and NO previous
Next number could be [9] so array [6,9] so previous is 6 then next number could be 2 so array [6,9,2] so previous is 9
Is that clear?  until [6,9,2,5,8,10,1,4,3,7] where 7 is current and previous is 3

Answer (score 0):

The question lack a bit of clarity. From the question what I understood is,

- The values in the array are **non repeating**
- You have a value at variable `current` and you want to find the previous value of the `current` which is stored in the array

And I will answer from what I understood. Using `indexOf()` gives you the index of current element from the array and you just need to subtract 1 from it to get the previous.

```js
var array = [1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5];

var current = 8;

var currentIndex = array.indexOf(current);

var previous = currentIndex !== 0 ? array[currentIndex-1] : 'N/A';

document.write('Previous Value: ', previous)
```

Comment: @user5451365 Happy to help! :)